# How can I insert two different templates at the same time when a button is clicked?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-template

I know how to insert a template into a page upon a url change (using `$routeProvider`) and an element with `ng-view`. But, I also want to insert another template into a different element at the same time. How do I do this? For example, I want to insert a template into the `replace-this` element at the same time I use `$routeProvider` to insert a template into `ng-view`.

```
<div class="replace-this">
    // I also want to insert a template here
</div>
<div ng-view>
    // main template goes here after url change from $routeProvider
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help that may be provided!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ui-router from angular-ui supports multiple parallel views. You may want to check it out: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need! It seems like this should be included with AngularJS (without needing the angular-ui-router dependency).